# Acausal form of $Z^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{z-a}\right)$

Tags: discrete-signals, z-transform, causality, inverse

We know that $Z^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{z-a}\right) = a^nu[n]$ if $|z| > |a|$.

In addition, $Z^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{z-a}\right) = a^{n-1}u[n-1]$ if $|z| > |a|$. This is the delayed version of the first one.

---

In acausal case, $Z^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{z-a}\right) = -a^nu[-n-1]$ if $|z| < |a|$.

But, I am confused about $Z^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{z-a}\right)$ if $|z| < |a|$. Is $Z^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{z-a}\right)$ equal to $-a^{n-1}u[-n-2]$ or $-a^{n-1}u[-n]$ or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless whether a sequence is causal or not, a multiplication with $z^{-1}$ is always a delay by one sample. I.e., if $X(z)$ is the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of $x[n]$, then $z^{-1}X(z)$  is the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of $x[n-1]$.

So if we know that for $|z|<|a|$

$$\mathcal{Z}^{-1}\left\{\frac{z}{z-a}\right\}=-a^nu[-n-1]$$

then we must have

$$\mathcal{Z}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{z-a}\right\}=-a^{n-1}u[-(n-1)-1]=-a^{n-1}u[-n]$$